Join in SQL searching for the nearest identical or smaller date
I have two tables T_VEN and T_COM.  In the first one I have the sales date of several products, in the second one I have the cost of these products per day.  I want to join the tables to inform the cost of the product on the day of sale, but when there is no cost on that day, I want it to find the cost of the immediately previous day.
e.g.: (the dates are in DD/MM/YYYY format)
T_VEN



PROD
DATE




1
01/02/2024


1
02/02/2024


2
02/02/2024


1
03/02/2024



T_COM



PROD
DATE
COST




1
01/02/2024
2.50


1
02/02/2024
3.50


2
01/02/2024
4.50






PROD
DATE
COST




1
01/02/2024
2.50


1
02/02/2024
3.50


2
02/02/2024
4.50


1
03/02/2024
3.50



I've tried doing joins in various ways, subqueries, extracting Max value with group by, join with case when clause, etc., but I'm having difficulties. I can easily connect in Excel with the XLOOKUP function with the Match_mode = -1 (exact match or next smaller. If an exact match is not found, the next smaller value is returned).

Hi - please format your data as tables so it’s readable, show the result you want to achieve based on your sample data, and include the SQL you’ve managed to write so far. You’ve also repeated the last paragraph for some reason

Is the third table the expected result or the actual result? What did you try?

What rdbms ? (what brand)

You can used the following approach
Join the tables on the product and date and than handle missing costs with a subquery
SELECT
    T_VEN.PROD,
    T_VEN.DATE,
    COALESCE(T_COM.COST, (
        SELECT TOP 1 T_COM_SUB.COST
        FROM T_COM AS T_COM_SUB
        WHERE T_COM_SUB.PROD = T_VEN.PROD
          AND T_COM_SUB.DATE < T_VEN.DATE
        ORDER BY T_COM_SUB.DATE DESC
    )) AS COST
FROM
    T_VEN
LEFT JOIN
    T_COM
ON
    T_VEN.PROD = T_COM.PROD
    AND T_VEN.DATE = T_COM.DATE;

Thanks
